# How to create a new user account in git (not github)?

Tags: linux, git, user-controls

I am trying to create new user in git. Where should I create? How can I create? I don't see any document about this anywhere! I am not talking about local repository configuration.

Comment: The really short answer is that git is not github (this is apparently a rather common confusion, and you wouldnt be alone in having thought this). The answer below explains that git doesnt have the concept of users that github does (but it does gave identities).

Answer (score 3):

In git, you don't really have users.

Commits have authors, and committers, but this happens at commit level, the repo is not listing authorized people to interact with it.

When you're setting your `user.name` and `user.email` config entries, you're not creating a user, you're just preparing your environment to be able to commit, since each commit has to have an author.

Accounts really happen only at a higher level, like Github that you ruled out explicitly for some reason.

Comment: I could see people use Gerrit to manage account. How does that work

Comment: Thank you! I managed to setup a Git server, but couldn't figure out how to login because this was unclear.